# Audio capture permission for an Android system app

Tags: android, audio

I was able to create a system app to capture the audio of other apps in an Android 10 system using the Android playback capture API. It failed to capture sound of some apps with target SDK of 28 however (it will work once I upgrade those apps to target SDK 29).

It's puzzling because according to the Android [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/av-capture#policy_manifest_audiomanager_audioattributes) and also [this blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/07/capturing-audio-in-android-q.html), system app by default should be able to capture the sound of other apps unless it was forbidden by the app intentionally (not in my case).

Comment: and what is the question? if any app is restricting recording its audio and thats system policy then you just won't hear this app, for shure you shouldn't exclude this app for this purpose, system just won'r let you to record this source

Comment: To clarify my question, my system app, say Alpha running in SDK 29, supposedly can record the other app, say Beta, because Beta doesn't have any restriction in its manifest. But in reality, Alpha can only record the audio of Beta if Beta has its target SDK in 29 as well. I just got silent audio if Beta stays in target SDK of 28, and there isn't any relevant error in logcat output. BTW, Alpha is running using the system UID, and resides in system folder /system/app, so I think it has the right priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help from my coworker, my app worked after my

1. upgrading the system app to a privileged app to have the CAPTURE_MEDIA_OUTPUT permission
2. setting the private field [mAllowPrivilegedPlaybackCapture](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/audiopolicy/AudioMixingRule.java#208)
   to "true" in the AudioMixingRule object.

The #2 above is the key that eluded me during my last failed try.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the solution. I am stuck in a similar problem where I want to capture chrome app audio.

Answer (score 1):

well, there is a note in linked doc ([in THIS paragraph](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/av-capture#capture_policy)), which is describing this behavior

> Note: The ability for an app's audio to be captured also depends on the app's targetSdkVersion.

> **By default, apps that target versions up to and including to Android 9.0 do not permit playback capture.** To enable it, include android:allowAudioPlaybackCapture="true" in the app's manifest.xml file.

> By default, apps that target Android 10 (API level 29) or higher allow their audio to be captured. To disable playback capture, include android:allowAudioPlaybackCapture="false" in the app's manifest.xml file.

Comment: Yes, I did have read this note, but my understanding is that it applies to non-system app only. In my case, my audio capture app is a system app.

Comment: I think it would be just kind-of insecure... When API29 was introduced most of apps didn't supported it yet (no flag) and some of them might play some "private audio". System won't know about privacy level, so it is silencing all non-declared apps just in case. And "declaration" may be understood as `allowAudioPlaybackCapture` flag introduction in code OR targeting change (as developer should read changelog and adjust some app attributes and code, incl. above flag)

Comment: Also some devs may decide that their audio data is so sensitive that it shouldn't be recorded by ANY app, besides that devs know about rooting and making some custom/own recording app as system one

Comment: Thanks, @snachmsm. What you said makes sense to me. On the other hand, the official document and the blog page quoted in my original post seem to suggest otherwise. I will need to dig deeper.

Comment: remember to let us know, post an answer when you find confirmation :) good luck!